# How to get the password of the current user - Swift Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to know, is there a way to retrieve the current user's password? Or just check if his password != "acertainvalue". I'm speaking when the current user is connected through Firebase authentification. Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the current password from the Firebase Authentication API as that would be a big security risk.

I'd also in general recommend against persisting the user's password as plaintext anywhere yourself, for the exact same reason.

If you need to check the user input against a specific value in your code, you should do that check right after you get the input from the UI - and before passing input on to Firebase.